# Updating fields in solr using SOLRNET - field data change

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am new to solr and I am trying to implement a CRUD using SOLRNET.

I have a problem updating fields in solr using SolrNet - atomic Update, here's the problem :

1. I am trying to update field "IsDeleted" and "IsSoldHidden" to solr using atomic update, here's what I've done.

```
 public void SetIsDeleted(string id)
        {
            GetInstance().AtomicUpdate(id, new List<AtomicUpdateSpec>
            {
                new AtomicUpdateSpec("IsDeleted", AtomicUpdateType.Set, "true")
            });

            GetInstance().AtomicUpdate(id, new List<AtomicUpdateSpec>
            {
                new AtomicUpdateSpec("IsSoldHidden", AtomicUpdateType.Set, "true")
            });

            GetInstance().Commit();
        }
```

```
 public ISolrOperations<T> GetInstance()
        {
            try
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<T>>();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error($"Unexpected error -> {ex.Message}", ex);

                return null;
            }
        }
```

this code is perfectly working at 1st-2nd call, but when I tried it again to use it, to update a field, there was an error occured,

[image: ERROR OCCURED WHILE CALLING ATOMIC UPDATE]

And the record in my solr was also transformed to this,
[image: RECORD TRANSFORMED - ISSUE]

I don't know what happen.
Am I doing it wrong ?
Any ideas about it? Thanks

Here is my schema.xml

```
  <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
 <field name="IsDeleted" type="boolean" uninvertible="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="IsManualSold" type="boolean" uninvertible="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true" default="false" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="IsSoldHidden" type="boolean" uninvertible="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
```

and here is the record that is successfully updated
[image: SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED -]

I've also researched on it, but no luck , I can't find any solution online

Comment: Which version of Solr?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335803/solr-throws-error-on-partial-update-after-upgrade-to-8-8

Comment: @MatsLindh I use solr 8.8.2

Comment: Then that's the issue - upgrade to 8.9: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13034